# Adding User Profile Fields to Wordpress Buddypress to Include "Favorites"

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to figure out a way for members on my Wordpress (Buddypress) site to pick their "favorite movies, books, etc."

It would be nice if, instead of members simply typing a list of these things, they could select from books already in the system, and add more as the please in the future.

I'm hoping that there is an easy answer to this, such as a plugin that I can use, or, at least, modify. Does anyone know of anything that I can look into?

Answer (score 1):

Your title asks how to add a user profile field.  Here is the code to add as many fields as you like.  Once you add the field, you can easily place additional inputs or options on the custom tab page for users to enter their own favorites.

```
function my_test_setup_nav() {
global $bp; 
$parent_slug = ‘test’;
$child_slug = ‘test_sub’;
//name, slug, screen, position, default subnav
bp_core_new_nav_item( array(‘name’ => __( ‘Test’ ),’slug’ => $parent_slug,’screen_function’ => ‘my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen’,'position’ => 40,’default_subnav_slug’ => $child_slug ) );
/* Add the subnav items to the profile */
// name, slug, parent_url, parent slug, screen function
bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( ‘name’ => __( ‘Home’ ), ‘slug’ => $child_slug, ‘parent_url’ => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $parent_slug.’/', ‘parent_slug’ => $parent_slug, ‘screen_function’ => ‘my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen’ ) );
bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( ‘name’ => __( ‘Random Page’ ), ‘slug’ => ‘random’, ‘parent_url’ => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $parent_slug.’/', ‘parent_slug’ => $parent_slug, ‘screen_function’ => ‘my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen234′ ) );
}

function my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen() {

//add title and content here – last is to call the members plugin.php template
add_action( ‘bp_template_title’, ‘my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen_title’ );
add_action( ‘bp_template_content’, ‘my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen_content’ );
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( ‘bp_core_template_plugin’, ‘members/single/plugins’ ) );
}

function my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen_title() {
echo ‘wptaskforce title’;
}

function my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen_content() {
echo ‘wptaskforce content’;
}


//random page content: 
function my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen234() {
//add content here – last is to call the members plugin.php template
add_action( ‘bp_template_content’, ‘my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen234_content’ );
bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( ‘bp_core_template_plugin’, ‘members/single/plugins’ ) );
}
function my_profile_page_function_to_show_screen234_content() {
echo ‘This is a random page.’;

} 
add_action( ‘bp_setup_nav’, ‘my_test_setup_nav’ );
```

Comment: You're using back ticks (`\``) instead of single-quotes (`'`), so this would create a lot of syntax errors.